# Getting slow perfarmence while playing animation in low memory devices

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

i'm new to iphone development. im developing app like talking tom. Here im using timers to animate images. for every animation im using separate timer. there is no problem in devices which have more then 5gb free space. But im gettin problem while playing in low memory devices. animation getting slow in those devices. Pleaase help me on this. thanks in advance. Please guide me in right way...

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your timers in different threads.

Comment: I have tried with different threads but not working. Anyway i'm poor in threading concepts. Could you please give me some sample code.